# Appending a list to another list through iteration in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

So, I've been trying to create a matrix consisting of multiplication tables up to n with python.

my function goes like this:

```
def multiplicationTable(n):
    tablePrint = []
    tempTable = []
    for s in range(n):
        s += 1
        tempTable.clear()
        for r in range(n):
            r += 1
            tempTable.append(r*s)
        tablePrint.append(tempTable)
#       print(tablePrint)
    return tablePrint
```

However, the returned list consists of n versions of the nth tempTable. If you remove the comment, you can see that through each iteration, every single instance within tablePrint gets edited. I had a friend explain roughly that lists are not data, but a memory address to a set of data, is this why this doesn't work?

Comment: Python lists are mutable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are appending the `tempTable` object repeatedly to the `tablePrint` object.  Thus, when you modify `tempTable`, you also modify all instances of that in `tablePrint`.  This is called *mutability*, in python lists are mutable.  Not all data in python is mutable, for example, your approach wold work if `tempTable` was a string.

To get around this issue for mutable data simply append a copy:

```
tablePrint.append(tempTable[::])
```

Here's a little example:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a
>>> a == b
True
>>> a is b
True       #They are the same object, changing a will change b
>>> b = a[::]
>>> a == b
True
>>> a is b 
False      #They are no longer the same object!
```

The issue you are having is discussed in length [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) (in a slightly different form)

Comment: Or better move the declaration(`tempTable = []`) inside the first loop.

Comment: `.copy()` is much more cleaner than slicing the whole list (however slower).

Comment: @Mephy, ```lst.copy()``` throws me an attribute error, is that a 3.x thing?

Comment: @wnnmaw apparently 3.3, and the documentation states it's equivalent to `[:]`: https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0):

This would be far simpler with either a list comprehension or nested `for` loops.

```
def multiplicationTable(n):
    return [[i*j for j in range(1,n+1)] for i in range(1,n+1)]

>>> multiplicationTable(3)
[[1, 2, 3],
 [2, 4, 6],
 [3, 6, 9]]
```

Using a more step-by-step nested `for` loop.

```
def multiplicationTable(n):
    table = []
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        l = []
        for j in range(1,n+1):
            l.append(i*j)
        table.append(l)
    return table

>>> multiplicationTable(3)
[[1, 2, 3],
 [2, 4, 6],
 [3, 6, 9]]
```